# LEFT Outer Join não funciona em LINQ quando é 0 a referencia? apenas null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6, join

Estou com dúvidas no Left Outer Join, estou utilizando MVC 5 C#, Net 4.5.2.

Tenho a Seguinte **Model Fornecedor**

```
 public class fechamentoFornecedor
    {
        public int FornecedorId { get; set; }
        public int Tipo { get; set; }
        public string FornecedorNome { get; set; }
        public bool IsEntrada { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<fechamentoMovimentacao> Movimentacoes { get; set; }
    }
```

E a **Model Movimentação**

```
  public class fechamentoMovimentacao
    {
        public int MovimentacaoId { get; set; }
        public int FornecedorId { get; set; }
        public byte Tipo { get; set; }
        public string Texto { get; set; }
        public DateTime Data { get; set; }
        public decimal Valor { get; set; }
        public bool IsEntrada { get; set; }

        public virtual fechamentoFornecedor Fornecedor { get; set; }
}
```

Inicialmente por uma lógica minha tentei fazer:

```
 public virtual fechamentoFornecedor? Fornecedor
```

Para tentar mostrar que ela poderia ser `Null`, não deu certo.

Então tentei fazer pela instrução `Linq`

```
var Linq = (from Movimentacao in db.fechamentoMovimentacoes
                       join Fornecedor in db.fechamentoFornecedores
                       on Movimentacao.FornecedorId equals Fornecedor.FornecedorId into output
                       from Fornecedor in output.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       where Movimentacao.Data.Year == hoje.Year && Movimentacao.Data.Month == MesNumber &&  Movimentacao.IsEntrada == IsEntrada
                       orderby Movimentacao.MovimentacaoId descending
                       select new MovimentacaoDataTable
                       {
                           MovimentacaoId = Movimentacao.MovimentacaoId,
                           Data = Movimentacao.Data,
                           Tipo = Movimentacao.Tipo,
                           FornecedorNome = Fornecedor !=null ? Fornecedor.FornecedorNome : "",
                           Texto = Movimentacao.Texto,
                           Valor = Movimentacao.Valor
                       });
```

Pelo que entendi o principal é aqui:

```
from Fornecedor in output.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Essa consulta não gera Erros, mas não traz resultados quando não tem relação No Fornecedor (`on Movimentacao.FornecedorId equals Fornecedor.FornecedorId` )

**Na** `Movimentacao.FornecedorId`, **quando não tem valores (relação com Fornecedor), eu insiro o valor 0 ao invés de `null` seria esse o problema?**

Comment: Se tu tirar o join com fornecedor, a consulta retorna algo?

Comment: Na verdade essa consulta já retorna, mas retorna somente quando o fornecedor existe, quando o Movimentacao.FornecedorId =0 dai ele não traz esse resultado..e a função do LEFT outer join seria justamente essa, trazer resultados mesmo que na 1ª tabela não tenha

Comment: E pq você salva 0 em vez de null?

Comment: banco de dados antigo, de terceiros, longa história....rs. Mas com certeza isso é um detalhe, só não sei como fazer o linq correto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu modelo não permite que o `Fornecedor` seja nulo. Ele precisaria ser assim:

```
public class fechamentoMovimentacao
{
    public int MovimentacaoId { get; set; }
    public int? FornecedorId { get; set; } // Aqui precisa ser Nullable.
    public byte Tipo { get; set; }
    public string Texto { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
    public bool IsEntrada { get; set; }

    public virtual fechamentoFornecedor Fornecedor { get; set; }
}
```